# Strom API in Windows

Tags: windows-xp, apache-storm

Can **Storm API** be installed in windows operating system ? I have placed Storm-0.8.1 in My Documents and updated the PATH variable,but the system is not recognizing storm command.I think I have downloaded the Linux version,so it is not working.So I am looking for Storm API version for **windows XP professional Service pack 3**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should try out Storm 0.9.0.1. According to [this blog post](http://storm-project.net/2013/12/08/storm090-released.html), there is much better Windows support.

Also, putting the Storm-jar in your path is not enough. I have only tried installing Storm on a linux machine, and I had to install Zookeeper and so on. For reference, check out [this blog post](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-multi-node-storm-cluster/) (but beware, this is for installing it on linux. Installing it on windows might be a lot harder)